# Ejecutar método luego de otro

Tags: python

> María va a enviarle a José un regalo, pero para que se haga el envío con éxito, se debe colocar un sello. Es decir, primero se el pone sello y luego se envía, de lo contrario no se envía nada.

No sé cómo hacer para que primero se ejecute el método *poner_sello* y luego el método *enviar*.
Como lo tengo cada vez que llamo el método *r.enviar* envía el regalo ignorando *poner_sello*.

```
class Envio:
    def __init__(self, emisor, receptor):
        self.emisor = emisor
        self.receptor = receptor
        
    def poner_sello(self):
        return 'Con Sello' 

    def enviar(self):                   
        print (self.emisor, 'ha enviado regalo a', self.receptor)
           
    
class Regalo(Envio):
    def __init__(self, emisor, receptor):
        super().__init__(emisor,receptor)
               
    def poner_sello(self):
        super().poner_sello()        
    
    def enviar(self):
        super().enviar()             
    
r= Envio('Maria', 'jose')
#r.poner_sello()
r.enviar()
r.enviar()
r.enviar()
```

Comment: Supongo que le idea será que verifiques si ya pusiste el sello. Puedes hacer esto agregando un campo booleano al objeto, que establezcas en true si llamar la función `poner_sello` y en `enviar` verifiques si es `true`.

Comment: Hola Mateo lo que acabas de describir es lo que necesito, ya pude resolver el problema, gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
class Envio:
    sello = False
    def __init__(self, emisor, receptor):
        self.emisor = emisor
        self.receptor = receptor
        
    def poner_sello(self):
        self.sello= True
        return 'Con Sello'

    def enviar(self):
        if sello:                   
          print (self.emisor, 'ha enviado regalo a', self.receptor)
      return "sello no esta puesto"
```

Comment: No olvides editar tu respuesta y explicar qué hace este código.

Comment: ¿No falta un `else`?